# show another tab when pressing button in a current tab

Tags: javascript, html

I want when I press Run button in tab 0 to go to tab 1. I try the following but it does not work.

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function x()
{
    $('#someNavTabs a:eq(' + 1 + ')').tab('show');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="TABS" class="yui-navset">
        <ul class="yui-nav" id="someNavTabs">
            <li id="TAB0" class="selected"><a href="#TAB0"><em>Run</em></a></li>
            <li id="TAB1"><a href="#TAB1"><em>Results</em></a></li>
            <li id="TAB2"><a href="#TAB2"><em>Help</em></a></li>
        </ul>
    <div class="yui-content" id="CONTENT">
    <!--TAB0-->
        <div id = "TAB0" class="active">
            <div class="MainContent">
                <input type='button' id='b' value='Run' onclick="x()">
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--TAB1-->
    <!--TAB2-->
</body>
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. By replace the javascript with this code:

```
this.yuiTabs = new YAHOO.widget.TabView("TABS", {activeIndex:1});

this.yuiTabs.set('activeIndex', 1);
```